# How do I detect the correct variables from strings in python

Tags: python, string, variables

I'm trying to build a program that takes a fairly simple chemical formula and balances it.

Let's say an example would be
Ca(Oh)₂  +  HNO₃  → Ca(NO₃)₂  +  H₂O

Since to my knowledge there's no way to hande subscript in python, I've decided on this formatting
Ca(Oh)_2 + HNO_3 = Ca(NO_3)_2 + H_2O, replacing the arrow with = and then using underscore for subscript.

So far I've managed to seperate the first and second part of the equation into the seperate elements.
So I have the lists

```
starters = ['Ca(Oh)_2', 'HNO_3']
products = ['Ca(NO_3)_2', 'H_2O']
```

This is where I'm stuck.

How can I go through the elements, and get the amount of each element.

I thought of storing it in a dict akin to

```
starter_amount = {element name; amount}
product_amount = {element name; amount}
```

Ideally it would also understand that e.g  2NO_3, means that there are 2N, and 6 O

Comment: Take a look on this old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009035/parsing-a-chemistry-formula-in-python. You can also try some libraries like: https://pypi.org/project/chempy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a complex question and resolving the stochastic formulae is just the first step. I hope the following function will help you. It parses your stochastic formulae to extract all atoms (btw: you should put H in upper case in Ca(OH)_2. Otherwise, it regards Oh as an element.).

Using this function, you get a list of all atoms in this product or educt.

```
def expand(stoch):
    f = ''
    for c in stoch:
        if c.isupper() or c == "(":
            f+=' '+c
        else:
            f+=c
    while '_' in f:
        i = f.rfind("_")
        if f[i-1]==")":
            l = 1
            start = i-2
            while l > 0:
                if f[start]=="(":
                    l-=1
                elif f[start]==")":
                    l+=1
                start-=1
            subform = f[start+2:i-1]
            subform = expand(subform)
            k = i+1
            while k<len(f):
                k+=1
                if not f[i+1:k].isdigit():break
            
            num = f[i+1:k]
            f = f[:start+1]+(subform+' ')*int(num)+f[k:]
            
        else:
            nc = 1
            subform = f[i-nc]
            while subform.islower():
                nc+=1
                subform = f[i-nc:i]

            k = i+1
            while k<len(f):
                k+=1
                if not f[i+1:k].isdigit():break
            
            num = f[i+1:k]
            f = f[:i-nc]+(subform+' ')*int(num)+f[k:]
    while '  ' in f: f = f.replace('  ',' ')  
    return f
```

The function takes your syntax for a stochastic formula, decomposes it and simlifies if by multiplying each element the number of times it should be.
The result would be:

```
print(expand("Ca(OH)_2"))
print(expand("C_6H_12(OH)_2"))

## Ca O H O H 
## C C C C C C H H H H H H H H H H H H O H O H
```

As it is recursive, it will be able to resolve nested parentheses:

```
print(expand("Ca_3(C_3H_5(OH)_3)_2"))

## Ca Ca Ca C C C H H H H H O H O H O H C C C H H H H H O H O H O H
```

If you apply it to your problem, I would suggest creating a dictionary that distinguishes between Product and Educt and lists the components and their atomic contents, so you can access it with an iterative program, later:

```
starters = ['Ca(OH)_2', 'HNO_3']
products = ['Ca(NO_3)_2', 'H_2O']

formula = {'Educts':[],'Products':[]}
for e in starters:
    atoms = expand(e).split(' ')
    while '' in atoms: atoms.remove('')
    formula['Educts'].append({'Formula':e,'Atoms':sorted(atoms)})
for p in products:
    atoms = expand(p).split(' ')
    while '' in atoms: atoms.remove('')
    formula['Products'].append({'Formula':p,'Atoms':sorted(atoms)})

for k,v in formula.items():
    print(k)
    for e in v:
        for k2,v2 in e.items():
            print('  - '+k2+': '+str(v2))
        print('')
 
## Output:
##
##Educts
##  - Formula: Ca(OH)_2
##  - Atoms: ['Ca', 'H', 'H', 'O', 'O']
##
##  - Formula: HNO_3
##  - Atoms: ['H', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O']
##
##Products
##  - Formula: Ca(NO_3)_2
##  - Atoms: ['Ca', 'N', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
##
##  - Formula: H_2O
##  - Atoms: ['H', 'H', 'O']
```

Or just this dict: `{'Educts': [{'Formula': 'Ca(OH)_2', 'Atoms': ['Ca', 'O', 'H', 'O', 'H']}, {'Formula': 'HNO_3', 'Atoms': ['H', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O']}], 'Products': [{'Formula': 'Ca(NO_3)_2', 'Atoms': ['Ca', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O']}, {'Formula': 'H_2O', 'Atoms': ['H', 'H', 'O']}]}`

Comment: OK, I had way too much fun with this excercise and wrote the rest of the program as well. It takes a chemical formula (without quantities) and solves the stochiometry. See here: https://github.com/Tarlanc/Side_Projects (script: chemical_Parser.py)